# Data Mapping Using Code

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I have an issue with a custom value mapping set.

Env-nt:

- Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219)
- Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1

Installed packages:

1. Data Exchange Framework SDK 2.0.1
2. Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1(to store items
   in Sitecore)

My goal is to read list of entities from web service and create/update items in Sitecore. Decided to use [data mapping in the code](http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DataExchangeFramework/v2.0.1/cookbooks/data-mapping/data-mapping-using-code/index.html).

1. [Custom Value Mapping Set](https://www.screencast.com/t/QWn9RCMYjIHp)
2. [Converter](https://www.screencast.com/t/vtFBWX9IKUCi)
3. [Mapping Set Class](https://www.screencast.com/t/HRhc1EGiu2w)
4. [Using in a Pipeline Step](https://www.screencast.com/t/oyq2suPRR)

I just followed [the manual](http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DataExchangeFramework/v2.0.1/cookbooks/custom-providers/implementing-a-provider/index.html), but didn't configure any mappings. In addition, added [couple Value Accessors(Property and Sitecore ones)](https://www.screencast.com/t/qkQUUNEjS) which are used to specify the unique field/property in "Resolve Product Item Step".

I received [following messages](https://www.screencast.com/t/g4lOfWLfV) when I tried to run Pipeline Batch(manually). I receive the same error for each entity(I have 5 ones). I can reach constructor of the converter in the debug mode, but I can't reach the constructor of a mapping set.

Will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "SupportedId" (point 2) correspond item template ID of "Product Value Mapping Set" (point 1) ?

Comment: Hi Vlad. Yep, it corresponds https://www.screencast.com/t/r4KjWUgs.

Otherwise, I think, I couldn't reach the breakpoint in the Converter.

Comment: Just for the test. Can you change (point 2) BaseItemModelConverter<ProductValueMappingSet> to BaseItemModelConverter<IMappingSet>?

Comment: Hm, it seems it helped, at least I have another error atm.

https://www.screencast.com/t/qfoWlFMm

Also, I changed not only the base class declaration:

https://www.screencast.com/t/ntAnGUmVfXLE

I wonder what should we have instead of Not Implemented collection?

public ICollection<IMapping> Mappings => throw new NotImplementedException();

I just used the provided example.

Comment: In (point 3) you have Mappings => throw new NotImplementedException() but in (point 4) "ApplyMappingStepProcessor" checks if "Mappings == null" and writes the error to the log. Try set empty collection.

Comment: Changed as on screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/h3g3Lf7U

Don't have any errors in the log now. However, all the target items are empty.

Comment: So now mapping runs it. Just debug it and see where mistake is

Comment: Yep, tried to debug. Seems I found the reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlad Shpak helped me to solve the issue.

Following was changed in the example(from the [documentation](http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DataExchangeFramework/v2.0.1/cookbooks/data-mapping/data-mapping-using-code/index.html))

1. [Converter was changed](https://www.screencast.com/t/EMF8L5JKe)
2. Initialization of Mappings property in class which implements IMappingSet:

   ```
   public ICollection<IMapping> Mappings => new List<IMapping>();
   ```
3. Decided to use SitecoreItemFieldWriter(Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Sc.DataAccess.Writers) instead of PropertyValueWriter.

   ```
   private static IValueWriter valueWriter1 = new SitecoreItemFieldWriter("ID");
   private static IValueWriter valueWriter2 = new SitecoreItemFieldWriter("Title");
   ```